# bash replace word in a : separated file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which has : separated data like

```
cat:dog:lion
cat:mouse:tiger
```

and I am trying to replace dog with anther value like fox for example using bash.
I need the changes to take place inside the file without changing the other data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three possible ways to do it:

1. `awk -F: -v OFS=: '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="dog") $i="fox"} 1'`
2. `perl -F: -lane 'print join ":" , map {$_ eq "dog" ? "fox" : $_} @F'`
3. `sed -r 's/^|$/:/g; s/:dog:/:fox:/g; s/^:|:$//g;'`

With sed and perl, use `-i` to edit the file in-place.
With awk: `awk ... > tmpfile && mv tmpfile orig_file`

Comment: can you please tell me what the 1 in the awk expr mean

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110351/shell-select-unique-row-of-flat-file/18111469#18111469

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed inline:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/(^|:)dog(:|$)/\1fox\2/g' file
```

OR on OSX:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/(^|:)dog(:|$)/\1fox\2/g' file
```

Becuase of `-i` flag changes will be saved in the file itself.

Comment: That will not change dog if it's the first or last field.

Comment: I was going to type awk answer but then noticed `I need the changes to take place inside the file` to posted sed command. I will tweak the sed command.